# Can I revoke read-write access request to a record of an entity owner in Dynamics-365?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In **Dynamics-365** crm, I want to revoke read-write access request to the owner of a record for specific reason.

I think it is not possible, but I am curious to know is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

If the Record is shared with user, Read write can be Revoked. But when a record is assigned or created by user and is Owner that means user already have at least Read, write rights for that particular Entity (Record) from security Role.

Summary: You cannot revoke Read-Write access but what you could do is remove Owner, add another owner and for that previous owner remove Security Role.